Is there an option to pass yum install a list of flags add a config flag to it?
I need to enable keepalived with a flag --enable-json in order for the keepalived_exporter to work.
Since I install packages using yum and I don't want to compile things myself, is there an option to tell yum install keepalived to add to the configure section the flag --enable-json ?

Have you looked at the yum options to determine this?

it doesn't seems that yum have such option when i reviewed --help this is why i wanted to check if someone is aware of a trick that can act the way i need ?

If you don't see an option in yum, then that's because it doesn't exist. Changing configuration options or how the package functions isn't something that yum does. The only way to do what you want is to either compile it with that flag yourself or create an rpm with that flag and then install it.
